# Create contact report with last added contacts

Tags: contacts, reports

I'm trying to achieve something that sounds trivial. In order to take a look and quantify how many new newsletter subscriber we have, I want to create a contact report listing all contacts belonging to a group (corresponding to a form), filtered by "added_date". Although this date information exists when I consult a contact, I can not find how to filter my contact report!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you provide more details about 'added_date' field. Do you have it as field on some form? Where you can see this field when consult a contact?

Comment: Not properly as a field, but contact creation date appears at the bottom right of the contact summary page. More than once I wanted to add this information as a column or filter to a report, without success. I am afraid that this is a functionality that needs to be implemented. Probably with Form Builder you can achieve it https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/afform.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to Search/Custom Searches and then run 'Search by date added to CiviCRM' and make a smart group from that list.  Then use that group as a filter in the report.